# Download File From Another Sever With Save as Dialogue Box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to download a file from another server with save as dialog box... I tried 1 example to download file from our server which worked but i don't know how to work for files which are hosted on another server.

If I try to download then i am getting It is not valid virtual path

Response.WriteFile(Convert.ToString(http://abc.com/sbe/test.pdf));

What should i do to download files from another server.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this code from a guy in asp.net forums.. His code help me to resolve my issue for a complete discussion check this link out : http://forums.asp.net/p/1772874/4847084.aspx/1?p=True&t=634655765939994111

Below is the code

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = @"http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/BackgroundWorker.pdf";
byte[] data = client.DownloadData(new Uri(url));

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "aspnet.pdf"));
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```